# Making GET Request after a POST Request in the same Session with OkHttp in Android Studio

Tags: android, okhttp

I am trying to retrieve some JSON data using OkHttp in Android Studio from the URL: www.duolingo.com/vocabulary/overview

Before I can get the data using this URL, it requires me to Login into the Duolingo server first (which makes sense since I want it to return data from my profile) so I make a POST request with my credentials using OkHttp. This is my code to achieve that:

```
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        String postUrl = "https://www.duolingo.com/2017-06-30/login?fields=";
        String getUrl = "https://www.duolingo.com/vocabulary/overview";
        String credentials = "{\"identifier\": \"something@email.com\", \"password\": \"Password\"}";
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(credentials, MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"));

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(postUrl)
                .post(body)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e)
            {
                Log.i("TAG", "ERROR - " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException
            {
                if (response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Log.i("LOG", "LOGGED IN");
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.i("LOG", "FAILED - " + response.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

The Response is successful and I get a `200 Response Code`.

Now since I have Logged In, I want to make a GET Request to the URL mentioned above to get the JSON Data. Problem is I do not know how to make a GET Request in succession to the POST Request I just made. OkHttp treats the 2 consecutive requests as separate while I want them to be treated as the same session.

Someone told me Cookies can help but I am totally oblivious to that and how they work. All help is appreciated!